# Magento 2 How to Render Child blocks in controller

Tags: magento2, cart, ajax, render-blocking, child

I want to remove the 'Proceed to Checkout' button when the qty reaches a specified limit. For that I add a condition check in this page

> ```
> module-checkout\view\frontend\templates\onepage\link.phtml
> ```

On qty update I have added an ajax call to the controller and passing the layouts as the ajax response and load the section. I am following the below link

[How to Render an HTML Using an Ajax Call in Magento 2 Module](https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-render-an-html-using-an-ajax-call-in-magento-2-module/)

In my controller I have added the below code

```
$block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart')
            ->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/methods.phtml')
            ->toHtml();
```

The issue is that, the checkout button is not loading since it is a child of this block.

```
    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.methods.bottom" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/methods.phtml">
        <container name="checkout.cart.methods" as="methods" label="Payment Methods After Checkout Button">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Link" name="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom" template="Magento_Checkout::onepage/link.phtml" />
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\QuoteShortcutButtons" name="checkout.cart.shortcut.buttons" />
        </container>
   </block>
```

Now, I need to render the child blocks along with this.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

How you are creating the new parent block, you will have to create the child blocks and embed them in the block you created:

checkout.cart.methods.bottom

You will do the same as you did for the child blocks, and then using the method addChild to include the child blocks in the parent.

I am pretty sure that there is a better way to achieve the requirements, maybe using knockout JS.